# Запись в файл, если он существует

Tags: c++, файлы

Как в современном C++ кроссплатформенно записать что-то в файл, только если он существует?

Comment: Создавайте обычный `::std::fstream` с флагами `in` `out`.

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2746168/7286264) обсуждают, как получить крестовый stream по open (понятно, что используя open ваш запрос делается стандартным набором флагов). Но, может лучше просто сделать `fdopen(open(...), "w")` и далее использовать `FILE *`?